# Date format in Def file

Tags: oracle

can someone help me in creating a date format in .def file. I pull the data from into Oracle data base table. I have a date column with format 'Jan 10 2017  2:44PM'. from .csv file. I am pulling the data using .def file given

```
COLUMN 'openBusinessDate' CHAR 100 'NULL' 'NOT KEY' 
COLUMN 'closeBusinessDate' CHAR 100 'NULL' 'NOT KEY' 
COLUMN 'openDatetime' CHAR 100 'NULL' 'NOT KEY' 
COLUMN 'closeDatetime' CHAR 100 'NULL' 'NOT KEY'
```

The date column in Oracle database table has datatype 'date' . Data has been inserted as Jan-10-2017 00:00:00.

I need to get the data as 'Jan-10-2017 14:22:00'

Thank you in advance